# Vertical Space Below ABSTRACT

Tags: abstract

ABSTRACT leaves a small vertical gap as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
There is a vertical gap in between the \textbf{Abstract} right above and this sentence. Can I get the size of this gap---is it \texttt{\textbackslash smallskip}, \texttt{\textbackslash medskip} or \texttt{\textbackslash bigskip}?
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Can I measure its exact height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways, you can add `\showoutput`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\showoutput
\showboxdepth=4
\begin{abstract}
There is a vertical gap in between the \textbf{Abstract} right above and this sentence.
Can I get the size of this gap---is it \texttt{\textbackslash smallskip},
\texttt{\textbackslash medskip} or \texttt{\textbackslash bigskip}?
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

which shows

```
....\penalty 0
....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/9 A
....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/9 b
....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/9 s
....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/9 t
....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/9 r
....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/9 a
....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/9 c
....\OT1/cmr/bx/n/9 t
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue -5.32494
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0
...\penalty -51
...\glue 10.0 plus 3.0 minus 5.0
...\glue -10.0 plus -3.0 minus -5.0
...\penalty -51
...\glue 10.0 plus 3.0 minus 5.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 4.75
...\hbox(6.25+1.75)x294.99994, glue set - 0.0665, shifted 25.00003
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x13.87491 []
....\penalty 0
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/9 T
```

so the additional space other than baselineskip between  Abstract and There... is

```
...\glue -5.32494
...\glue 10.0 plus 3.0 minus 5.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
```

Alternatively you can look at the source in `article.cls`

```
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \if@twocolumn
        \section*{\abstractname}%
      \else
        \small
        \begin{center}%
          {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
        \end{center}%
        \quotation
      \fi}
      {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
```

so you get the space  from the center and quotation  lists cancelled out by .5em, note that `\end{center}` and `\quotation` lists don't add a double list space as list use `\addvspace` so latex only adds the maximum of the space after center and the space before quotation.

This construct is kept for historical compatibility, it isn't exactly a model of how to specify document spacing in a coherent way....

Comment: The thing I find peculiar about this is the use of `em` as the unit for vertical spacing.

Comment: @barbarabeeton one of the more peculiar aspects, also that it's a fixed (font dependent size) as a negative length counteracting the class-specified display spacing around lists, so if the class were to set the `center` up with a smaller vertical offset, the abstract could overprint the title having the negative space at all seems "interesting" the fact that it's in em is just icing on the cake...